# How to solved the problem loading error in DependencyPropertiy in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to binding a command bar with dynamically with primary commands. Here is the XAML:

```
<CommandBar IsOpen="True"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Style="{StaticResource TagsCommandBar}"
            DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:BindableCommandBarBehavior PrimaryCommands="{x:Bind ViewModel.AppBarButtonList, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</CommandBar>
```

And, the dependency property for commands are as follows:

```
public class BindableCommandBarBehavior : Behavior<CommandBar>
    {
        public ObservableCollection<AppBarButton> PrimaryCommands
        {
            get
            {
                return (ObservableCollection<AppBarButton>)GetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty PrimaryCommandsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PrimaryCommands", typeof(ObservableCollection<AppBarButton>), typeof(BindableCommandBarBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<AppBarButton>), UpdateCommands));

        private static void UpdateCommands(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            if (!(dependencyObject is BindableCommandBarBehavior behavior))
                return;
            if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged oldList)
            {
                oldList.CollectionChanged -= behavior.PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
            }

            if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged newList)
            {
                newList.CollectionChanged += behavior.PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
            }

            behavior.UpdatePrimaryCommands();

        }


        private void PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePrimaryCommands();
        }


        private void UpdatePrimaryCommands()
        {
            if (AssociatedObject == null)
                return;

            if (PrimaryCommands == null)
                return;

            AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Clear();

            if (!(PrimaryCommands is IEnumerable enumerable))
            {
                AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Clear();
                return;
            }
            if (PrimaryCommands != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Clear();
                foreach (var command in PrimaryCommands)
                {
                    if (!AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Contains(command))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Add(command);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Log.D(this, ex.Message);
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            if (PrimaryCommands != null)
            {
                PrimaryCommands.CollectionChanged -= PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is working fine when I am adding `AppBarButtonList` dynamically. But the problem occurs during loading the saved `AppBarButtonList`. It showing the exception of :

```
Element is already the child of another element.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IVector`1.Append(T value)
   at BindableCommandBarBehavior.UpdatePrimaryCommands()
```

I need kind help to solve this problem and load and add `AppBarButtonList`.

Comment: We could not reproduce your issue with above, could share AppBarButtonList content or share a mini sample for us?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate back and forth may cause this error. In that case, you can make copy of `PrimaryCommands` items. Hope this will help you.